# Sanity Studio: Customg Form Components

Tags: reactjs, sanity

I am trying to roll out a custom preview component. Here is the code.

```
//character.jsx

import characterActor from './characterActor'

function MyPreviewComponent1(props) {
  console.log(props.characterActor)
  ....
}

export default defineType({
  name: 'character',
  title: 'Character',
  type: 'object',
  components: {
    preview: MyPreviewComponent1, 
  }, 
  fields: [
    defineField({
      name: 'characterName',
      title: 'Character Name',
      type: 'string',
    }),
    defineField({
      name: 'characterDesc',
      title: 'Character Description',
      rows: 2,
      type: 'text',
    }),
      defineField({
      name: 'characterActor',
      title: 'Actor',
      type: 'array',
      of: [{type: 'characterActor'}],
    }),
      ],
  preview: {
    select: {
      title: 'characterName',
      characterActor: 'characterActor',
     }, 
  }
})


//characterActor.js

export default defineType({
  name: 'characterActor',
  title: 'Role Vs Actor',
  type: 'object',
  fields: [
    defineField({
        name: 'actor',
        title: 'Actor',
        type: 'reference',
        to: [{type: 'actor'}],
      }),
    defineField({
        name: 'status',
        title: 'Status',
        type: 'string',
        initialValue: 'longlist',
...
```

However, in the props.characterActor the actor field is only the reference not the actual value from the actor name field. How can I de-reference (or do anything else) so the props actually have the value.

Many Thanks